# How to store ISBN in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, isbn

How can I  use input ISBN number like this 01316295910 store in an array?And let it print on screen list this :  **ISBN 0  1  3   1   6   2   9   5    9   10(<=X)**

Here is my code :

```
int[] A = new int[10];
Console.Write("input ISBN:");
for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
     A[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
     Console.WriteLine("ISBN",A[i]);
 }
 Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: anyway you have failed to provide how the input format looks like. And I doubt you should be using ReadLine.

Comment: An ISBN is not an integer. Why are you trying to use it as one? It's a string that happens to consist of the characters from `0` to `9` and `-`, but you don't do mathematical calculations with the values. (If you did, the `-` would indicate subtraction, right? What purpose would that subtraction serve?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest this step by step so you can get the logic

```
//declare the array
int[] A = new int[10];
Console.Write("input ISBN:");

//Read the isbn from the console
string input = Console.ReadLine();
//turn that into a char array
char[] characters = input .ToCharArray();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("ISBN: ");
//iterate
for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
{
    sb.append(characters[i]).append(" "); 
}
//print it
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Comment: Thanks  you . Pretty appreciated .